# remove coloraxis legend on a Google calendar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Would like to remove the coloraxis legend on a Google calendar chart. The color axis sits at the top right of the chart. My chart is trying to illustrate dates of activity for Kansas amphibians and reptiles and the type of activity (calling vs not) for frogs and toads. The coloraxis as displayed is uninformative... however another solution would be to change the coloraxis label to a text label (e.g. calling, other active).

Example at http://webapps.fhsu.edu/ksfaunatest/account.aspx?o=30&t=3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["calendar"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Activity' });
dataTable.addRows([
[new Date(2012, 4, 3), 1],
[new Date(2012, 4, 16), -1],
[new Date(2012, 5, 6), -1],
// many rows removed
[new Date(2012, 7, 15), 1],
[new Date(2012, 7, 25), -2],
]);
var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));
var options = {
legend: 'none',
title: '',
calendar: {
daysOfWeek: '',
yearLabel: {
fontName: 'Times-Roman',
fontSize: 1,
color: '#000000',
bold: false,
italic: false
},
}
};
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
drawChart();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to remove the entire legend, and working with WhiteHat's answer I tweaked it to this. Basically I tried to find the relevant attributes that only affected the legend and hid them:

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
   $($('#calendar_basic text')[0]).hide();
   $($('#calendar_basic text')[1]).hide();
   $($('#calendar_basic text')[2]).hide();
   $('#calendar_basic linearGradient').hide();
   $('#calendar_basic')
       .find('[fill-opacity="1"]').hide();
});
```

Comment: DanIreland... thank you. I used your suggestion but it is showing a single number. Example: https://webapps.fhsu.edu/ksHerp/account.aspx?o=30&t=4

Comment: ahhh.... got it... 
   $($('#calendar_basic text')[3]).hide();

Answer (score 1):

no *standard* options exist for removing the legend or even changing the text

however, once the chart's `'ready'` event fires,
you can change manually...

```
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    $($('#calendar_basic text')[0]).text('Calling');
    $($('#calendar_basic text')[1]).text('');
    $($('#calendar_basic text')[2]).text('Other');
  });
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    $(window).resize(drawChart);
    drawChart();
  },
  packages: ["calendar"]
});
function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Activity' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [new Date(2012, 4, 3), 1],
    [new Date(2012, 4, 16), -1],
    [new Date(2012, 5, 6), -1],
    [new Date(2012, 7, 15), 1],
    [new Date(2012, 7, 25), -2],
  ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));
  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    title: '',
    calendar: {
      daysOfWeek: '',
      yearLabel: {
        fontName: 'Times-Roman',
        fontSize: 1,
        color: '#000000',
        bold: false,
        italic: false
      },
    }
  };
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    $($('#calendar_basic text')[0]).text('Calling');
    $($('#calendar_basic text')[1]).text('');
    $($('#calendar_basic text')[2]).text('Other');
  });
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="calendar_basic"></div>
```